# PHP unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in path

Tags: php

```
echo <<<HTML  
    <a name="$news_id" id="$news_id"></a>  
    <h3>$news_title</h3>  
    $news_body  
    <p><em>Posted: $formatted_date</em></p>  
    <hr />  
HTML;
```

How can I fix the code above? When I run it an error message says:

> unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in [path]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
echo " 
<a name='$news_id' id='$news_id'></a>  
<h3>$news_title</h3>  
$news_body  
<p><em>Posted: $formatted_date</em></p>  
";
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked :) Will mark as best answer after 10mins.

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning the HEREDOC expression to a string, and then echoing the string. So ...

```
$myString = <<<HTML
    <a name="$news_id" id="$news_id"></a>  
    <h3>$news_title</h3>  
    $news_body  
    <p><em>Posted: $formatted_date</em></p>  
    <hr />  
HTML;  
echo $myString;
```

Comment: Another great solution. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I use this syntax a lot because it means I can mix up single quotes, double quotes and variables without having to use escape characters. @Danyal's certainly let's you do all of these, but can become tricky if you want to use double quotes in the attributes.